# Customize contents in swagger-ui.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am using spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and swagger 2.9.2, everything is fine except that I want to simplify the content.

First, I want to remove the `base URL` under title:

```
[ Base URL: localhost:7777/ ] 
http://localhost:7777/v2/api-docs
```

And, I want the `API blocks` and `Models block` to be opened on visiting, not until I click the name.

And, I want the `select a spec` list on the top banner to be removed or hidden.

I don't know if there is a way to do these with java API, I can't find any solution other place.

The picture I tried to upload:
[image: the picture I tried to upload]

Seems that I am not allowed uploading picture yet, don't blame me if the picture above is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

here i find a class helping to configure swagger UI:

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration
```

and here is my usage:

```
    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
                .deepLinking(false)
                .displayOperationId(false)
                .defaultModelsExpandDepth(1)
                .defaultModelExpandDepth(1)
                .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.MODEL)
                .displayRequestDuration(true)
                .docExpansion(DocExpansion.LIST)
                .filter(false)
                .maxDisplayedTags(null)
                .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.METHOD)
                .showExtensions(false)
                .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA)
                .validatorUrl(null)
                .build();
    }
```